# Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object" in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous

Everythings works fine and i m also getting the data but i m getting this javascript error .

I have following **network request**

```
    data: {
    patient: null
    }
    methods: {
    
    
    //call methods to add patients
    setPatient(patient) {
          this.patient = patient;
        },
      }
//network request in navigation guard
  async beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    await axios
      .post(route("api.patient.ids"), { ids: [to.params.id] })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.data.length) {
          next((vm) => {
            // console.log(typeof res.data[0]);
            vm.setPatient(res.data[0]);
          });
        }
      });
  },
```

[image: chrome dev tool error]

somebody could explain whats causing the problem ?

Comment: you probably initialize some variable that you use in render as null, and then fill it with the data from your network request. Vue tries to render your component for the first time _before_ the request returned the data, hence it throws an error about being unable to use null as an object. Do add a closure in your markup not to render the portions of the page that require data from the network request before it's ready

Comment: i m passing the patient data into props of other component 
  <health-condition
        :patient="patient"
         @openForm="toggleFormTable"
     ></health-condition>

Comment: if patient is null or undefined before the network request, and you're trying to render some of its props you'll get this error. Add protection and you'll be fine

Comment: @grreeenn, *"add protection"* doesn't mean anything to someone who doesn't know what you're talking about. You could have as well said: *"wear a helmet" (or a mask, given the context)*. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place a `v-if="patient"` on any template element which requires `patient` to be an object. Your `patient` is `null` initially, until the API call returns and you commit it.

In your case:

```
<health-condition v-if="patient"
                  :patient="patient"
                  @openForm="toggleFormTable" />
```